# Android Nested Fragment Lifecycle On Configuration Change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-lifecycle

I have an activity running a support viewPager that consists of fragments (the support library variant), which themselves consist of one of three possible fragments. Given that the Android OS destroys and recreates activities on configuration changes (notably screen rotation), I have decided to retain the middle fragments as they run AsyncTasks. The children also may be running other threads so they need to be retained as well. My immediate concern is that:

1) Although the fragments in the viewPager have their onDetach() method called, the children of those fragments never reach onStop(), onDestroy() or onDetach(). Regardless of whether their instances are being retained or not, surely onDetach() should be called since the activity is destroyed.

2) Despite never being stopped, the references to the child fragments are lost; when the activity is recreated and the middle fragments are reattached they fail to find the children using getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(key).

EDIT - some relevant code from the middle fragments that are run by the viewpager:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(cachedLocation==null) {
        new WaitForLocation().execute(mCallback);
    }
    else {
        swapFragment(LTAG);         
    }
}
```

The above is calling swapFragment correctly after recreating, and proves that the middle fragment is retained. However:

```
public void swapFragment(String key) {
    //use passed key to organise displayed fragment in shell
    FragmentManager childFragMngr = getChildFragmentManager();
```

'childFragMngr' does not contain any fragments - mAdded and mActive are both null in the debugger at this point, which is strange because the onStop() and onDetach() methods are never touched for the children.

```
    if(childFragMngr.findFragmentByTag(key)==null) {
        Fragment mFragment = null;
        if(key.equals(listFragmentTag)) {
            //instantiate a list fragment
            mFragment = createListFragment();
        }
        else if(key.equals(detailFragmentTag)) {
            //instantiate a detail fragment
            mFragment = createDetailFragment();
        }
        }
        if(mFragment!=null){
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.subfragment_shell, mFragment, key)
                                                        .addToBackStack(null)
                                                        .commit();  
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `but if code is desired I can include some` yes, it is! Why would you describe your code and **not** post it? ;-)

Comment: I am running into the same problem.  I downgraded to an older version of the support library and now it appears to be working!  I am looking into it more to figure out what version I downgraded to and try to confirm.  Perhaps there is a bug with the newest version of the support library?

Comment: I downgraded to [rev 19.1.0](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.1.zip) from revision 20.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. I might try reverting if I end up taking that path. For now I am trying an alternate design where the viewPager is actually nested in a fragment, instead of the viewPager hosting the nested fragment pages. I'll post back how things are going.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in the support library and I have created a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74222).

Comment: Is this still a problem? I can't get my nested fragment views (togglebutton, edittext) to restore state.